# How come I cannot override customization of XIB using initwithnibname

Tags: iphone, ios

How come the CheckBox does not load any of the images if I do this?  It only works if I set them from the XiB files.  I can do this from Xib, but if I do need more complex things to customize, I won't know how.

I set a break point there so I know these things are being called.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        [tcCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [tcCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [tcCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"]
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        tcCheckBox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;

        **// Custom initialization**
     }
    return self; 
}
```

Comment: Ok I found out I need to put it into viewDidLoad, but what is the point of this // Custom initialization mean within this function?

Comment: For non-UI related stuff, e.g. initializing your class instance variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `initWithNibName:bundle:` doesn't instantiate the nib right away but just initializes the view controller, so all your `IBOutlets` are still nil at this point. Override `viewDidLoad` for custom UI initialization, this method gets called when the nib gets instantiated and all your IB connections are resolved.